# Estoy intentado usar la api de Google en React Native para el autocompletado y no me funciona

Tags: react-native, expo

Esto y intentando importar GooglePlacesAutocomplete de la api de google y no funciona el autocompletado taampoco me da errores, tengo ingresada la API KEY y revise el codigo varias veces pero no logro ver porque no funciona. Lo estoy desarrollando en EXPO

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles.js";
import { useState } from "react";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";

const DestinationSearch = () => {
    const [fromText,setFromText] = useState('');
    const [destinationText, setDestinationText] = useState ('');    
        return (
    <SafeAreaView style= {{flex:1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
         value={fromText}
         onChangeText={setFromText}
         style={styles.textInput}
         placeholder="From" />
        <TextInput 
         value={destinationText}
         onChangeText={setDestinationText}
         style={styles.textInput}
         placeholder="Where to?" />
         <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
           placeholder='Search'
           onPress= {(data, details = null) =>{
             console.log(data, details);
           }}
           query={{
            key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            lenguage: 'es',
           }}
           />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default DestinationSearch;
```